# Patching a Textured Plaster Wall

Tags: walls, plaster, patch

We have an interior wall that is textured plaster in our 1934 Tudor home. We are going to flip the pictured light switch to the other side of the wall, so that we can mount a television on the wall.

I am getting confused reading up on patching plaster walls for a few reasons:

1. The little patch kits sold at Home Depot etc, I'm not sure if these are for dry-wall only and if they will patch the size hole we will have.
2. If we can avoid it, we don't want to re-do the entire wall, since the walls were recently re-done and are in good shape overall.

Anybody who knows how complicated this will be, your thoughts and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

James[image]

Comment: This sounds like an invitation for a general discussion which is _not_ a good fit for this forum. If you have a _specific_ question you'd like to ask that would be much more appropriate.

Comment: I use drywall repairs exclusively, even on plaster. There's no good reason for you to use old-school techniques just because you're in plaster. There are a number of questions about this on the site.

Comment: It would help greatly if we knew what kind of lath you're dealing with. Any hunches?

Comment: Get a blank plate and paint to match.  I can't tell if that is really textured plaster or generations of roller stipple marks in paint.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! It is wooden lath behind the plaster. However, there would be no lath where the electrical box is currently.